# Update SQL with optional parameters

Tags: c#, sql

I am working on a C# program which calls SQL Server stored proc.

As a mostly front end developer my knowledge of backend is limited.

Below is a (super simplified) version of SP I have. The goal is C# program to be able update a specified field without need to send all field values to the database.
For example if I need to only update name then I send a null to DB

```
  ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Tester] 
        @ID int,
        @name as varchar(50)=null,
        @age as int=null
    AS
    BEGIN       
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        Update Test
        Set
        Name=isnull(@name,name),
        Age=isnull(@age,Age)
        Where ID=@id
        END
```

I want to know if there is an issues with the above method. So far all of my tests are successful.

Comment: _"I want to know if there is an issues with the above method"_ - why not just use an ORM instead?

Comment: Yes, there are issues -- this approach will make it impossible to explicitly set columns to `NULL` should you want to or need to, and you also have to take care that a "NULL update" (`SET Column = Column` everywhere) is not actually a no-op on the database end -- the column is still physically modified, meaning triggers fire and I/O happens to update indexes. These are not necessary deal breakers, but they're still worth being aware of.

Comment: Great feedbacls. Thanks. So assuming I never need to updatea Field to be set to  Null and if there are not heavy triggers on these fields this method should be OK?

Comment: @SNash That's a pretty big assumption... project requirements change all the time and you don't want to be stuck with a procedure that you can't change for fear of breaking its dependents.

Comment: Using something like *Dapper* would be easier for something like this, aside your proc requires Age be supplied, is that just oversimplification

Comment: @stu that was a typo , age is aslo can be null but id is required.  OK I have never worked with object mappers. how simple is that to learn and work with?

Comment: How long is a pirce of string? Dapper is easy to get started with and not as complex or tightly bound as others especially if you prefer full control over your queries - all imho of course.

Comment: Does Dapper work with  standard ASP.NET WebForms? Every resource I found so far are referring to .NET Core .